# Call method from another component VueJS version 1

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to call the method from another component in let's say parent component... So, let's say I have notie.vue and there's my method named 'flash' and I want to call that after API request when I get success.

So let's say this is the case: after get API I want to call something like this with parameters ---> **notie.success('notification type', 'notification message')**

Here's the code:

**Props are defined like this**

```
props: {
    type: {
        default: 'info',
        required: false
    },
    content: {
        default: 'This is just demo text',
        required: false
    },
    visible: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}
```

**Here's data**

```
data: function () {
    return {
        show: true
    }
}
```

**Here's method**

```
methods: {
    flash: function () {
        this.show = true;
    }
}
```

**Here's HTML code**

```
<div class="notie" v-bind:class="[{active: show}, type]" v-on:click="close()"> 
    <div class="notie__icon" :class="type"></div>
    <div class="notie__content" v-text="content"></div>
</div>
```

Here for example i want to call my notie component

```
submit: function () {
    this.$http.post('/api/books/add', {
        data: this.data,
    }).then(function (response) {
        // I want to use notie component right here to notice to users.
    }, function (response) {
    });
}
```

**So my question is how can I call flash() after API request on success or error?**

Comment: Where is the code to call your API?

Comment: Is that important? I just want to call it anywhere in my app.

Comment: But you said you want to call after API request on success or error

Comment: That was just an example where I want to call it... The main problem is that how can I call that method which is in my notie component in any other component?